# Mongoose Schema type Object Id Mapping

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Backend Code:
This is orderModel.js

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const orderSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
      ref: "User",
    },
    orderItems: [
      {
        name: { type: String, required: true },
        qty: { type: String, required: true },
        image: { type: String, required: true },
        price: { type: String, required: true },
        productId: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          required: true,
          ref: "Product",
        },
      },
    ],
    deliveryAddress: {
      address: { type: String, required: true },
      area: { type: String, required: true },
      // gender: { type: String, required: true },
      postalCode: { type: String, required: true },
      district: { type: String, required: true },
      division: { type: String, required: true },
      country: { type: String, required: true, default: "Bangladesh" },
    },
    paymentMethod: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    paymentStatus: {
      id: { type: String },
      status: { type: String },
      update_time: { type: String },
      email: { type: String },
    },
    taxPrice: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      default: 0.0,
    },
    deliveryCost: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      default: 0.0,
    },
    totalPrice: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      default: 0.0,
    },
    discount: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      default: 0.0,
    },
    isPaid: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
      default: false,
    },
    paidAt: {
      type: Date,
    },
    isDelivered: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
      default: false,
    },
    deliveredAt: {
      type: Date,
    },
  },
  {
    timeStamps: true,
  }
);

const Order = mongoose.model("Order", orderSchema);

export default Order;
```

This is orderController.js -

```js
import asyncHandler from "express-async-handler";
import Order from "../models/orderModel.js";

// review: desc => Create New Order
// review: route => POST api/orders
// review: access => Private

const createOrder = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const {
    orderItems,
    deliveryAddress,
    paymentMethod,
    taxPrice,
    deliveryCost,
    discount,
    totalPrice,
  } = req.body;

  if (orderItems && orderItems.length === 0) {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error("No order items");
  } else {
    try {
      
      const order = new Order({
        orderItems,
        user: req.user._id,
        deliveryAddress,
        paymentMethod,
        taxPrice,
        deliveryCost,
        discount,
        totalPrice,
      });
      console.log("ORDER CREATED", order);
      const createdOrder = await order.save();

      console.log("ORDER saved", createdOrder);

      res.status(201).json(createdOrder);
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(400);
      throw new Error("Invalid order data", error);
    }
  }
});

// review: desc => GET order by id
// review: route => GET api/orders/:id
// review: access => private

const getOrderById = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const order = await Order.findById(req.params.id).populate(
    "user",
    "name email"
  );

  if (order) {
    res.json(order);
  } else {
    res.status(404);
    throw new Error("Order not found");
  }
});

export { createOrder, getOrderById };
```

Frontend Code:

```js
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch(
          createOrder({
            orderItems: cartItems,
            deliveryAddress: addressObject,
            paymentMethod,
            taxPrice: vat,
            deliveryCost,
            discount,
            totalPrice,
          })
        );
      };
```

Here When I am sending request to backend, It's giving me validation error. As - orderItems.0.productId: Path `productId` is required. Why I am getting this error ? mongoose should not map data and get productId from sent cartItems, where is a field is _id ? Your time and  help is most appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: OrderItems is an array and should have productID as ObjectId.

Comment: https://github.com/saniul06/Full-Featured-Ecommerce-By-MERN-STACK-deployment-version-/blob/main/backend/controllers/orderController.js     
Could you pls look this link, here he is doing same thing, but working for him.

Comment: So, You need to check what are you sending to the backend. orderItems should be an array and should have productId in it. Use console.log.

Comment: okay got it, I sent order items as an array already but I didn't assign productId field in the cartItem, as I thought mongoose will map through it. But I have to define it . Thanks for your help